# How does this define work?

Tags: scheme

I have this piece of scheme code:

```
(define (x . y) y)
(x 1 2 3)
```

and I know it equivalent to:

```
'(1 2 3)
```

But i can't understand why.

What does the first line of code do?

Thank you.

Comment: They are not equivalent. (x 1 2 3) is the same as (list 1 2 3). And what do you want? R6RS is a very readable document and there is everything about function definitions and parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first line `(define (x . y) y)` is equivalent to `(define x (lambda y y))`, according to [5.2  Definitions](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-8.html#%_sec_5.2)(the last clause).

And `(lambda y y)` is a procedure; when called all the arguments will stored in a newly allocated list. e.g. `list` could be defined as `(define list (lambda xs xs))`. (See [4.1.4  Procedures](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-7.html#%_sec_4.1.4) the second form of formal parameters.)

So `(x 1 2 3)` is equivalent to `(list 1 2 3)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I just have a doubt: why `(lambda y y)` accept unlimited number of arguments? Which is the difference with `(lambda (y) y)`? (That accept only one argument). I'm reading the r6rs standard, but i'm missing something. Thank you again.

Comment: It accepts an unlimited number of arguments because when you say `x . y` or `(lambda y y)` you are defining an improper list. Thus in that context `y` can refer to a single element or a whole list of elements. This would be different than defining  `(lambda (y) y)` because in that context y is a single element within a list.

Comment: The formal parameters part of `(lambda y y)` is `y`, and of `(lambda (y) y)` is `(y)`. Procedures which accept unlimited number of arguments are sometime useful, so many programming languages support it. In lisp, there are many ways to denote variadic arguments. CL uses special symbol &rest for instance. And Scheme uses only cons: the formal parameters part is a chain of pairs(fixed part, maybe empty) and ends in empty list(can't accept any more arguments) or ends in a symbol(accept unlimited number of arguments).

Comment: Some examples: `(a b)` is `(a . (b . '()))`, which has fixed part `a` and `b` and ends in empty list, so `(lambda (a b) ...)` accept two arguments exactly.  `(a b . c)` is `(a . (b . c))`, which has fixed part `a` and `b` and ends in symbol `c`, so `(lambda (a b . c)` accept N(N>=2) arguments, the first two binds to `a` and `b`, the rest binds to `c`.  `(lambda y ...)` is a special case, which has no fixed part.

Comment: So, if i understand: in `(lambda y ...)` the `y` binds to the wall list? Is it correct?

Comment: @Aslan986 yes. And some more examples: `(define f (lambda (a . b) b))`, `(f) => error`, `(f 0) => ()`, `(f 0 1) => (1)`, `(f 0 1 2) => (1 2)`. `(define g (lambda a a))`, `(g) => ()`, `(g 1) => (1)`, `(g 1 2) => (1 2)`.